# lstm RNN input error

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, tensorflow

I am trying to design a simple lstm in tensorflow. I want to classify a sequence of data into classes from 1 to 10.

I have *10 timestamps* and data X. I am only taking one sequence for now, so my batch size = 1.
At every epoch, a new sequence is generated. For example X is a numpy array like this-

```
X [[ 2.52413028  2.49449348  2.46520466  2.43625973  2.40765466  2.37938545
     2.35144815  2.32383888  2.29655379  2.26958905]]
```

To make it suitable for lstm input, I first converted in to a tensor and then reshaped it (batch_size, sequence_lenght, input dimension) -

```
X= np.array([amplitude * np.exp(-t / tau)])
print 'X', X

#Sorting out the input
train_input = X
train_input = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_input)
train_input = tf.reshape(train_input,[1,10,1])
print 'ti', train_input
```

For output I am generating a one hot encoded label within a class range of 1 to 10.

```
#------------sorting out the output
train_output= [int(math.ceil(tau/resolution))]
train_output= one_hot(train_output, num_labels=10)
print 'label', train_output

train_output = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_output)

>>label [[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Then I created the placeholders for tensorflow graph, made the lstm cell and gave weights and bias-

```
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [batch_size,len(t),1])
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [batch_size, num_classes])

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden)
output, state = rnn.dynamic_rnn(cell, data, dtype=tf.float32)

weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([batch_size, num_classes, 1])),
bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))

#training
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(output,weight) + bias)
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(target * tf.log(prediction))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
minimize = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)
```

I have written the code this far and got error at the prediction step. Is it to do with the input shapes? Here is the traceback---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raisa/PycharmProjects/RNN_test1/test3.py", line 66, in <module>
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(output,weight) + bias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1024, in matmul
b = ops.convert_to_tensor(b, name="b")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 566, in convert_to_tensor
ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/constant_op.py", line 179, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/constant_op.py", line 162, in constant
tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 390, in make_tensor_proto
tensor_proto.string_val.extend([compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 44, in as_bytes
raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' % bytes_or_text)
enter code here
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7f5c04251910>
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I'm not certain, but why do you have separate weights for each element in the batch? In other words, what happens if you set weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes, 1]))?

Comment: Is this reproducible in 1.0? This looks like it's trying to convert a Variable to a string Tensor, which doesn't make sense to me. Can I get a full reproducible example?

Comment: Can try to run it line by line to check exactly which line is giving the error?